# Issue with boolean operations with MPI (MPICH2) and Fortran

Tags: fortran, boolean, mpi, mpich

When performing reductions on logical values in Fortran with MPI (`MPI_LAND` operation), MPICH2 returns invalid values of the `logical` type, which return `.true.` to both `value` and `.not.value`.

For example, this is the result of an `MPI_ALLREDUCE` of the `logical` `my_value = rank>=0` in the sample program below:

```
on CPU 0, the local boolean value is 00000000000000000000000000000001
on CPU 0, the logical and of all values is T; its negation is T
on CPU 0, logical AND bits = 11111111111111111111111111111111 negation bits = 11111111111111111111111111111110
```

MPI seems to have performed a *bitwise* AND instead of an operation on the logical variables. MPI bug or am I just doing something wrong here? BTW - note that:

- using old-style `mpif.h` for portability
- MPICH2 v1.4.1 + gfortran 10.2.0

```
program test_mpi_land
   implicit none
   
   include 'mpif.h'
   
   ! Local variables
   integer :: ierror,ncpu,cpuid
   logical :: my_bool,all_ok
   integer, parameter :: master_node = 0
   
   ! Init MPI; get basic info
   CALL MPI_Init(ierror)
   CALL MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ncpu, ierror)
   CALL MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, cpuid, ierror)
 
   ! Each MPI process sends .true. to reduction
   my_bool = cpuid>=master_node
   CALL MPI_AllReduce(my_bool,all_ok, 1, MPI_LOGICAL, MPI_LAND, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)
 
   if (cpuid==master_node) then 
     print '(A,I0,A,B32.32)',    'on CPU ',cpuid,', the local boolean value is ',my_bool
     print '(A,I0,2(A,L0))',     'on CPU ',cpuid,', the logical and of all values is ', all_ok, '; its negation is ',.not.all_ok
     print '(A,I0,2(A,B32.32))', 'on CPU ',cpuid,', logical AND bits = ',all_ok,' negation bits = ',.not.all_ok
   endif    
 
   CALL MPI_Finalize(ierror)   
   
end program test_mpi_land
```

Comment: Forget the MPI, your Fortran is doing something very strange - `on CPU 0, the logical and of all values is T; its negation is T` - how come .Not. True = .True.?

Comment: Interesting perspective - I thought the issue was somewhat related with the non straightforward relationship between C and Fortran booleans - but would only think of the MPI side?

Comment: Well, according to [gfortran manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/gfortran.pdf): _For Boolean (LOGICAL) arguments, please note that GCC expects only the integer value 0 and 1. If a GNU Fortran LOGICAL variable contains another integer value, the result is
undefined. As some other Fortran compilers use −1 for .TRUE., extra care has to be taken – such as passing the value as INTEGER._ So, maybe the MPI implementation returns a representation of the `LOGICAL` variable  which does not match what gfortran wants? the bit-wise representation of the result is definitely neither 0 or 1

Comment: That would certainly be possible if you use MPI compiled for a different compiler.  1. change `include 'mpif.h'` to `use mpi`. Do you get an error message? If yes, you know why you should never use the include ever again. 2. Find out how the MPI library was installed and install one configured for your compiler.

Comment: My guess is that you are using MPICH that was compiled for Intel Fortran and not for gfortran.

Comment: MPICH 2 supports gcc/g77: its installation README says: _For gcc/g77
1) create a makefile
2) add –I…mpich2\include
3) add –L…mpich2\lib
4) add –lmpi (for g77: -lfmpich2g) _, that's exactly what I'm doing. But of course, I can't use the `.mod` files as they come from an old gcc version

Comment: You cannot use MPI compiled for a different compiler. Get one compiled for your gfortran.

Comment: And while you're at it, you might want to upgrade your MPI implementation as well. MPICH2 1.4 is a decade old at this point.